# Setting up domain

Tags: domains, dns, connections

I am currently trying to finish setting up my domain to my google site, but I am stuck. I verified the third-party domain to the google site via site settings. In the settings it shows verification of ownership, but when I try to search my domain now to see if it is working, it takes me to a page, that states..

```
This site can’t be reached 

www.theleightonhaus.com unexpectedly closed the connection.

Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED.
```

How can I fix this issue I have tried to read everything, I have tried to mess with DNS settings, is it possible that I simply do not have a google workspace account and google is turning the connection off the website?

Comment: The A Record points to  142.250.185.211 - are you certain that is the correct IP address?

Comment: It works for me. `$ curl --head http://www.theleightonhaus.com` says moved permanently to `https://www.theleightonhaus.com/`  the `$ curl --head https://www.theleightonhaus.com` says "200 OK"